# How to sketch this function

Tags: linear-algebra

$\left( f(x) \right ) =\min_{t<x}\left(t^2\right)$

How do I sketch this function for all real x? I don't get what minimum means in this context how do I sketch such a function when t is in the function but x isn't the square term?

Comment: Are you sure the subscript is $t<x$ rather than $t \leq x$?

Comment: for sure it's the former

Comment: hmm... in that case, the minimum value might not exists and the function is not well defined.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Suppose $f(x) = \min_{t\le x} t^2$.

Let's illustrate how to evaluate this function value at $-1$ and $1$.

$f(-1) =\min_{t \leq {-1}}t^2$, since $t^2$ is a decreasing function for non-positive value, the minimimum value occur at $-1$, hence $$f(1) =\min_{t \leq {-1}}t^2=(-1)^2=1$$

$f(1) = \min_{t \leq 1} t^2$, we can differentaite the function $t^2$, set the derivative to be equal to $0$ and verify that the minimum value is $0$. Hence $f(1)=0$.

Another hint: The graph that you plot can be described in the following form

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & ,x \leq a \\ h(x) &, x>a\end{cases}$$

where I am sure you have seen $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ before.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Understood it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

$t^2$ is a decreasing function from $-\infty$ to $0$, so that its smallest value for $t\le x\le0$ is achieved at the bound $x$ and is $x^2$.

$t^2$ has a global minimum at $x=0$, with value $0$, so that its smallest value for $t,0\le x$ is $0$. Hence

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\le 0\to x^2,\\x\ge 0\to 0.\end{cases}$$

[image]